# Can DbParameter instance of same name and type be shared with multiple DbCommand instances?

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

Is it efficient or possible to share same DbParameter  object with multiple commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, One cannot. A quick check gave runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if a class is mutable (ADO.NET parameters are quite definitely mutable), then it's a bad idea to do this.

By contrast, references to immutable classes *can* be shared between callers without any danger of corrupting data.